# Uniqueness of UUID substring

Tags: substring, unique, uuid

We track an internal entity with java.util generated UUID. New requirement is to pass this object to a third party who requires a unique identifier with a max character limit of 11. In lieu of generating, tracking and mapping an entirely new unique ID we are wondering if it is viable to use a substring of the UUID as a calculated field. The number of records is at most 10 million.

java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString() // code used to generate

Quotes from other resources (incl. SOF):
"....only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for approximately 100 years would the probability of creating a single duplicate reach 50%."

"Also be careful with generating longer UUIDs and substring-ing them, since some parts of the ID may contain fixed bytes (e.g. this is the case with MAC, DCE and MD5 UUIDs)."

We will check out existing IDs' substrings for duplicates. What are the chances the substring would generate a duplicate?

Comment: It depends on how the UUID was generated and which 11 characters you're selecting. For example, if you chose the last 11 digits of a v1 UUID, you would have tons of collisions. In general, UUIDs were designed to be unique in their entirety and make no promises about substring uniqueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance of the Birthday Problem. One formulation of B.P.: Given a choice of *n* values sampled randomly with replacement, how many values can we sample before the same value will be seen at least twice with probability *p*?

For the classic instance of the problem,

> *p* = 0.5, *n* = the 365 days of the year

and the answer is 23. In other words, the odds are 50% that two people share the same birthday when you are surveying 23 people.

You can plug in

> *n* = the number of possible UUIDs

instead to get that kind of cosmically large sample size required for a 50% probability of a collision — something like the billion-per-second figure. It is

> *n* = 16^32

for a 32-character string of 16 case-insensitive hex digits.

B.P. a relatively expensive problem to compute, as there is no known closed-form formula for it. In fact, I just tried it for your 11-character substring (*n* = 16^11) on Wolfram Alpha Pro, and it timed out.

However, I found an efficient implementation of a closed-form estimate [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/birthday-paradox/). And here's my adaptation of the Python.

```
import math

def find(p, n):
   return math.ceil(math.sqrt(2 * n * math.log(1/(1-p))))
```

If I plug in the classic B.P. numbers, I get an answer of 23, which is right. For the full UUID numbers,

```
find(.5, math.pow(16, 32)) / 365 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 100
```

my result is actually close to 7 billion UUID per second for 100 years! Maybe this estimate is too coarse for large numbers, though I don't know what method your source used.

For the 11-character string? You only have to generate about 5 million IDs total to reach the 50% chance of a collision. For 1%, it's only about 600,000 total. And that's probably overestimating safety, compared to your source (and which we are already guilty of by assuming the substring is random).

---

My engineering advice: Do you really need the guarantees that UUIDs provide aside from uniqueness, such as non-enumerability, and assurance against collisions in a distributed context? If not, then just use a sequential ID, and avoid these complications.

Comment: The birthday paradox assumes that the choices are uniformly randomly distributed. However, UUIDs and substrings of UUIDs are not required to be uniformly randomly distributed. For example, the first character of the third block is probably 4. The first two blocks of a type 1 UUID are monotonic increasing, and the last block is constant for each generating system.

Comment: @Raymond Chen I do wave my hand at this property of UUIDs in my answer, but this comment really makes it concrete!